# Cognos Report Studio crosstab

Tags: cognos

How to create Page break in `Cognos Crosstab` without using master detail relationship? Or is there any other option for pagination on the data item of Crosstab?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Page Set instead of using one Page.
Click the Page Explorer and select Report Pages. Then add Page Set and set up query and Grouping and Sorting property.